# host.json; meaning of batchsize

Tags: function, azure

Does it make sense to set batchSize = 1? In case I would like to process files one-at-a-time?

Tried batchSize = 1000 and batchSize = 1 - seems to have the same effect

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:15:00",
  "aggregator": {
    "batchSize": 1,
    "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
  }
}
```

Edited:
Added into app setings:
WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1

[image: Azure function monitor]

Still the function is triggered simultaneously - using blob trigger. Two more files were uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your misunderstand the `batchSize` meaning with **aggregator**. This `batchSize` means Maximum number of requests to aggregate. You could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#aggregator) and about the [aggregator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-the-aggregator) it's configured to the runtime agregates data about function executions over a period of time.

From your description, it's similar to the `Azure Queue` batchSize. It sets the number of queue messages that the Functions runtime retrieves simultaneously and processes in parallel. And If you want to avoid parallel execution for messages received on one queue, you can set batchSize to 1(**This means one-message-one-time**).

Comment: I have found out that pararell processing depends on number of azure functions instances. So if you have only one azure function instances batchSize  = 1 works well. That is not my case I have more AF instances in my resource grp. But still I am not sure of it. Anyway setting batchSize=1 on my resource grp does not trigger one messagage-one-time processing.

Comment: @Michal Štěpán, you check the batch [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings), you could find this setting eliminates concurrency only so long as your function app runs on a single virtual machine (VM).And you have multiple instances.So if you want it works you could restrict the instances with WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1.

Comment: @Michal Štěpán, this is this setting [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out). And you are using Consumption plan or Azure App Service Plan?

Comment: I have Azure App Service Plan. Where should I put  WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1. In application settings? Thanks Chen for helping. Building functions directly on portal (C#).

Comment: @Michal Štěpán, yes just go to the **Configuration** in the portal, set this variable. And check this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings).

Comment: Edited original question with the results.

Comment: flushTimeout 00:00:30 Maximum time period to aggregate. Maybe set flushTimeout to 00:00:00? Any ideas? (flushTimeout Maximum time period to aggregate). Update - that's not good idea :). Throwing error -  flushTimeout must be > 00:00:00.

Comment: @Michal Štěpán, I have explained what's aggregator for, and yo still use it. You need configure the queue batchsize. This is because it uses queues behind the scenes for blob trigger. You could fin it here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1452

Comment: @George Chen if running in an app service plan and WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1 and we have a batchsize > 1, will parallel executions happen? If yes, how? Since we’ve limited to a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Configuration-Settings

WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT = 1

Set a maximum number of instances that a function app can scale to. This limit is not yet fully supported - it does work to limit your scale out, but there are some cases where it might not be completely foolproof. We're working on improving this.

I think I can close this issue. There is no easy way how to set one-message-one-time feature in multiple function apps instances.